# Blank space in array with String splitter

Tags: java, arrays, regex

My objective is to separate the numbers from the string, but in my array's first position i get a blank space. So i need help for that not to happen.

```
str1 = "Y=9x1+29x2";
String[] split2 = str2.split("[^-?.?0-9]+");
```

Comment: (1) What is your expected output, and why?  (2) What kinds of substrings do you hope the regex in your `split` will match?  The way your question is written right now--"separate the numbers from the string"--is too vague.  I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: (3) What do you hope the output will be if the input is `"3+4-5"`?

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear. Actually i want my output to be a number in each array position like split2[0]=9, split2[0]=1, split2[0]=29, split2[0]=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blank space at the start is due to presence of non-digit character at the start of your input.

You can remove all non-digits at start before splitting:

```
String linha = "Y=9x1+29x2";
String[] split = linha.replaceFirst("[^-.\\d]+", "").split("[^-.\\d]+");
for (String tok: split2)
    System.out.println(tok);
```

**Output:**

```
9
1
29
2
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. The only problem is that it also removes '-' for negative numbers and '.' for double ones.

Comment: So i tryed `String[] split = linha.replaceFirst("[^-?.?0-9]+", "").split("[^-?.?0-9]+");` and i worked exactly as i intended. Ty very much for the help.

Comment: @RodrigoCosta It's still wrong.  If you're putting `?` inside square brackets, then you still don't understand regexes.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is rather vague, but after looking at it, I'm guessing that you want to extract the numbers out of the string, where a "number" has this format: an optional minus sign, followed by an optional decimal point, followed by one or more digits.  I suspect you also want to include numbers that have digits followed by a decimal point followed by more digits.

I'm guessing this is what you want, because of the `?` you put in your regex.  The problem is that inside square brackets, `?` doesn't mean "optional", and it doesn't mean "zero or one of something".  It means a question mark.  The regex `[^-?.?0-9]` means "match one character that is not a digit, a period, a hyphen, or a question mark".  A pattern in square brackets always matches one character, and you tell it what characters are OK (or, if you begin with `^`, what characters are not OK).  This kind of "character set" pattern never matches a sequence of characters.  It just looks at one character at a time.  If you put `+` after the pattern, it still looks at one character at a time; it just does so repeatedly.

I think what you're trying to do is to take a pattern that represents a number, and then say "look for something that doesn't look like that pattern", and you tried to do it by using `[^...]`.  That simply will not work.

In fact, `split()` is the wrong tool for this job.  The purpose of `split` is to break up a string whose *delimiters* match a given pattern.  Using it when the strings you want to **keep** in the array match a given pattern doesn't work very well, unless the pattern is extremely simple.  I recommend that you create a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and use the `find()` method in a loop.  `find()` is set up so that it can find all matching substrings of a string if you call it repeatedly.  This is what you want to accomplish, so it's the right tool.